# Prisma Schema: now() + X hours with Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, prisma

I'm using Mongodb as the provider with Prisma. How can I set my `expireAt` field to be now()+15 hours for example?

```
datasource db {
    provider = "mongodb"
    url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model UserToken {
    id                 String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
    email              String   @unique
    createdAt          DateTime @default(now())
    expireAt           DateTime? @default(now() + XHours) // <-- ??
}
```

If I try to use `dbgenerated("NOW() + interval '1 year'")` for example, it gives an error saying:

```
Error validating field `expireAt` in model `UserToken`: 
The `dbgenerated()` function is not allowed with MongoDB. 
Please use `auto()` instead.
```

When I use auto() it says it doesn't accept any arguments. I'm looking to make it `now()+X hours`

Comment: I have no clue about prisma but try `now() + 1000*60*60*15` for 15 hours

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit The Prisma schema doesn't accept math operations like that for whatever reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible at the moment. I would recommend creating a [Feature Request](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature_request.md&title=) so that setting a default time other than now() in MongoDB can be supported.

For now, you would need to calculate expiredAt in your application code manually while creating a UserToken.

In your application, you can do something like this to add 15 hours to the current time.

```js
let time = new Date();
time.setHours(time.getHours() + 15);
```

Comment: To clarify, not possible in MongoDB, but if using Postgres it could work with `dbgenerated("NOW() + interval '1 year'")` right?